# Codeigniter Sending Email throwing error

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

I am spending hours trying to send email in CI from server. In localhost, it worked fine.

In **config/email.php** I have added the following:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';    
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'username@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '*******';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

and in **auth.php**(I am using tank auth) in function for sending email, I have added this,

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

I am getting errors as:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
.....................................................
```

I have enabled ssl in server. I found lot of posts related to the same and followed them. But yet it is not sending email.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to load config..

change

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

To

```
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

However, have a look in this blog post for more information.
http://www.blog.orionwebtech.net/codeigniter-sending-email-via-smtp-gmail/

You can also check SSL is enabled -

You can enable SSL in your PHP config. Look up php.ini and find a line with the following:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Uncomment it.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Hope work.